# How the condition will work if the attribute value and the ID value are the same through the loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, getattribute

```
<style>

    .heading {
        color: red;
    }
    
    .button {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    .skyblue {
        background-color: skyblue;
    }
</style>
```

If <h1> tag's "data-mh" and <button> tag's id has similar attribute
    than if I click on the button the button background-color will change.
    And the attribute will print on the P tag. My code is working with first
    button but it's not working with the second or othersbuttons.
/* how can do it by loop */

```
<h1 class="heading" data-mh="item1">Hello World</h1>
<button class="button" id="item1">Click Here</button>

<h1 class="heading" data-mh="item2">Hello World</h1>
<button class="button" id="item2">Click Here</button>

<h1 class="heading" data-mh="item3">Hello World</h1>
<button class="button" id="item3">Click Here</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<!-- This Paragraph tag will print my attribute -->

<!-- HTML End -->

<script>
    var x = document.querySelector(".heading").getAttribute("data-mh"); // This variable is to get Attribute of "data-mh"
    var y = document.querySelector(".button"); // Button selection. By clicking this button I will get print my Attribute
    var z = y.getAttribute("id"); // Getting button id to compaire with "data-mh" attribute
    y.onclick = function() {
        //If X (ID) and Z (Attribute) matching then working this Condition
        if (x == z) {
            y.classList.toggle("skyblue");
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x+" "+z; // This line of code will print my Attribute on P tag
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Look up querySelectorAll which will give you all the relevant elements in a collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
const headings = document.querySelectorAll(".heading");

for (const button of buttons) {
  for (const heading of headings) {
    button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      const x = button.getAttribute("id");
      const z = heading.getAttribute("data-mh");
      if (x == z) {
        button.classList.toggle("skyblue");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x + " " + z;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This code does the task by looping over each button and doing all the setup for event listeners and comparision.

```js
// select all the buttons
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");

// loop over each one
for(const button of buttons)
{
  // add an on click listener
    button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    // get the button ID
    const x = button.getAttribute("id");
    /// get the previous element's (the heading's) data-mh attribute
    const z = button.previousElementSibling.getAttribute("data-mh");
    // compare them
    if(x == z)
    {
      button.classList.toggle("skyblue");
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x+" "+z;
    }
  });
}
```

Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/w3d0z8Ly/

Answer (score 0):

check my answer:-

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".heading"); // This variable is to get Attribute of "data-mh"
    var y = document.querySelectorAll(".button"); // Button selection. By clicking this button I will get print my Attribute
    // var z = y.getAttribute("id"); // Getting button id to compaire with "data-mh" attribute
    function btnClick(e) {
      for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if(e.getAttribute("id") == x[i].getAttribute("data-mh"))  {
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x[i].getAttribute("data-mh");
        }
      }
      for(var j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
        y[j].classList.remove("skyblue");  
      }
      e.classList.add("skyblue");
    }
```

```css
.heading {
        color: red;
    }
    
    .button {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    .skyblue {
        background-color: skyblue;
    }
```

```html
<h1 class="heading" data-mh="item1">Hello World</h1><button class="button" id="item1" onClick="btnClick(this)">Click Here</button>

<h1 class="heading" data-mh="item2">Hello World</h1>
<button class="button" id="item2" onClick="btnClick(this)">Click Here</button>

<h1 class="heading" data-mh="item3">Hello World</h1>
<button class="button" id="item3" onClick="btnClick(this)">Click Here</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Please check this